# Как сделать авто заполнение Foreign Key в Entity Framework?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-core

```
public class MSDBcontext : DbContext
{
    public MSDBcontext(DbContextOptions<MSDBcontext> options) 
        : base(options)
    {

    }
    public DbSet<Mails> Mails { get; set; }
    public DbSet<MailsResult> MailsResults { get; set; }
    
    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<Mails>()
        .HasOne(b => b.MailsResult)
        .WithOne(i => i.Mails)
        .HasForeignKey<MailsResult>(b => b.MailsId);
    }
}

public class Mails
{
    public int MailsId { get; set; }
    public string Subject { get; set; }
    public string Body { get; set; }
    public string Recipient { get; set; }

    public MailsResult MailsResult { get; set; }
}

public class MailsResult
{
    public int MailsResultId { get; set; }
    public DateTime CreatedDate { get; set; }
    public string Result { get; set; }
    public string FailedMessage { get; set; }

    public int MailsId { get; set; }
    public Mails Mails { get; set; }
}

[HttpPost]
public async Task<ActionResult<Mails>> PostMails(Mails mails)
{
    MailsResult result = new MailsResult();
         
    result.MailsId = mails.MailsId;
    result.CreatedDate = DateTime.Now;
    result.Result = "OK";
    result.FailedMessage = null;

    _context.Mails.Add(mails);
    _context.MailsResults.Add(result);

    await _context.SaveChangesAsync();

    return CreatedAtAction("GetMails", new { id = mails.MailsId }, mails);
}
```

У меня в базе связь один к одному, как мне сделать автозаполнение внешнего ключа в таблице MailResult?
Я получается заполняю MailResult данными об ошибка связанных с сообщением которое пришло Mails. И поэтому Внешний ключ должен совпадать с id Mails.

Вот такое решение я придумал, но у меня большие сомнения в том что оно правильное:

```
    _context.Mails.Add(mails);
    await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
            
    result.MailsId = new { id = mails.Id }.id;
    result.CreatedDate = DateTime.Now;
    result.Result = "OK";
    result.FailedMessage = "OK";
    _context.MailsResults.Add(result);
    await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
```

Comment: 3.1.25 Версия Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer

Comment: PK Вот это поле у меня `public int MailsResultId { get; set; }`

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov Нет у меня в этой сущности MailsId по Identity задано, в этом и проблема. Я не понимаю как мне передать MailId в поле MailsID сущности MailsResult

Comment: но я проверил, если в ручную MailId прописать все работает

Comment: `mails` это данные типа `Mails` Входящие из вне. Я сохраняю их в конце  `_context.MailsResults.Add(result); await _context.SaveChangesAsync();`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Итак, третья редакция ответа.
Судя по добавленному куску кода, `mails` - это новая сущность, ещё не существующая в БД.

```
MailsResult result = new MailsResult { CreatedDate = DateTime.Now, Result = "OK" };

mails.MailsResult = result; // <--

_context.Mails.Add(mails);
_context.MailsResults.Add(result);

await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
```

Не используйте свойства-ключи напрямую. Используйте навигационные свойства. EF сам задаст необходимые ключи.

Comment: protected override void OnModelCreating У меня тут проблема. Я использую Microsoft.EntityFameWorkCore, а данный способ работает для Data.Ebtity

Comment: Я чет забыл про это указать, я через ModelBuilder могу манипулировать, но я так рань никогда не делал и там нет атрибутов ".HasRequired(x => x.Mails)
                                     .WithOptional(x => x.MailsResult);"

Comment: Проблема вообще не в `Mails` проблема в `MailResult` а конкретнее в его поле `mailsId`. я заполняю базу данных данными и у меня между сущностями `MailResult` и `Mails` связь `1 к 1`. Я в одном этом методе заполняю 2 сущности `Mails` и `MailsResult`. Мне нужно чтоб foreign key `(MailsId)` из сущности `MailsResult` автоматически был равен полю  `(MailsId)` из сущности `Mails`. Чтобы когда я заполнял поля мне нужные, мне не приходилось бы указывать foreign key. Чтоб он автоматически подставлялся к полю `(MailsId)`  сущности `MailsResult`.

Comment: Если я сделаю identity полю `(MailsId)`сущности MailsResult. то будет проблема. Так как может быть какой-нибудь баг и вся программа ляжет

Comment: Большое спасибо, это оказалось проще чем я думал